# Why am I getting low effective samples and high rhats with multilevel Bayes models using brms?

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I've been using the `brms` package in R to run some multilevel Bayes models. I've been getting some strange results however (such as extreme predictions and not capturing effects I would expect it to), and when looking at the model diagnostics my Rhats looks way too high and effective sample size way too low.

I think a lot of my problems stem from the fact that I'm trying to model the variance of parameters as well as their location. I've tried to use the methodology discussed here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_distreg.html

To try to diagnose the root of the problem, I've created simplified versions of my problem with synthetic data.

Even with data as simple as the below, however, similar issues seem to pop up:

```
library(brms)
n <- 100
Group1 <- data.frame(Group = "Group1", y = round(rnbinom(n, size = 10, mu = 20)))
Group2 <- data.frame(Group = "Group2", y = round(rnbinom(n, size = 1, mu = 15)))
df <- rbind(Group1, Group2)
df$x1 <- df$y + rnorm(n, 5, sd = 3)
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())
mod <- brm(bf(y ~ x1 + (1|Group),
              shape ~ (1|Group)),
              family = negbinomial(), data = df)
```

Looking at `summary(mod)` returns effective samples of about 2, and Rhats well in excess of 1000.

What could be the cause of this and what could I do to address it?

Comment: Note that you've made a model with zero error in it. In particular, try `plot(df$x1, df$y)`. My guess is that this is the root of. your issue.

Comment: Yup you're right it should have read `df$x1 <- df$y + rnorm(n, 5, sd = 3)`. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the bigger issue I've been having with my bigger 'real' dataset. I'll try to turn that into a reproducible example (which I thought I had here) and come back here if I manage to do so.

Comment: @CliffAB I've updated the code to amend the previous error and increased model complexity to more closely reflect my 'real life' problem.